# pig how to filter distinct couples (pairs)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig. I have a Pig script which generates tab-separated pairs between two element. One pair for each line, for example:

```
John   Paul
Tom    Nik
Mark   Bill
Tom    Nik
Paul   John
```

I need to filter out duplicate combinations. If I use DISTINCT, I filter out double "Tom Nik" entry. The result is:

```
John   Paul
Tom    Nik
Mark   Bill
Paul   John
```

The problem with this approach is that I am left with both "John Paul" and "Paul John", which for my purposes should be treated as the same (same combination).
Is there a way to remove permutate combinations?

Comment: Right now you essentially have the pairs as lists. What you really want to treat them as is sets. Try creating a bag with the two names as elements. A bag is unordered.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain clearly. I have 2 columns. The first one can be accessed by $0 and the second by $1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how string comparisons is implemented in Pig, but it may be worthwhile to try something like:

```
-- A is your input
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(($0 < $1 ? ($0, $1) : ($1, $0))) ; 
C = DISTINCT B ;
```

By sorting the names so that the 'smaller' always appears first both `John Paul` and `Paul John` should now be in the same order, making the `DISTINCT` eliminate one.

However, this approach all depends on how the string comparison is implemented. For example if it compares length then the `John Paul` case will not be filtered correctly.

Comment: thank you for your help! This is a perfect solution for my problem!